# Is there a online folder service that allows to keep a normal folder structure so JS, HTML and CSS files can find each other like a locale folder

Tags: software-development, sharing, file-sharing

I am sorry if this question is hard to understand, not sure how to phrase it.

We have developed many JavaScript games that run on PhaserJS and currently we have them run locally on the website in an iframe.

Currently the iframe links to the index.js file that is the start point of the game and that connects/depends on many HTML, JS and CSS files in different folders.

We would like to move them to an online folder so we can update them without touching the website, where then we can call the index.js file and it would run like if it was running locally where it would have access to the files it needs in other folders.

Is there such a service where you can "host" folders and allow folders to connect to each other just like a normal computer and run PhaserJS games and HTML.

Or do you guys have another suggestion to the problem.